# Infinite loop created when accessing computed property from view ie9 emberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, internet-explorer-9

I have a computed property that is used to return either true or false for an if statement in the view.  thinking it might be a scope problem of some kind.  In ie9 once the value is changed from true to false (or visible to hidden) it freezes, I can't even access any of my other programs.  I can only use my keyboard when in task manager because if I use my mouse to focus on any window it freezes like everything else.  This error, of course, does not occur in chrome or firefox but because of requirements it has to be set up for ie9.

Our library versions are: Ember-1.0.0 handlebars-1.0.0
We're hoping to update those soon but not sure when that will be

Has anyone else experienced their browser crash when a computed property is being accessed by the view?

```
showSelect: function(key, value) {
    debugger;
    try {
        //if (this.get('hideIt')) return false;
        return (this.get('groups')!=null && this.groups.get('content')!=null && this.groups.get('content').length>0);
    } catch (err33) {
        App.notificationSystem.displayNotification('Landing Page Group Dropdown vis failure.', 'error', 'error', true, err33);
        return false;
    }
}.property('showSelectP').cacheable()

{{#if view._context.showSelect}}
    {{view Ember.Select 
        contentBinding="view._context.groups.content"
        valueBinding="view._context.current"
        optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
    {{/if}}
```

Thanks for any help

Something to add, we created a work around but it's a bit hackish for our likes but does the job for the time being.  the commented out line in the showSelect function is part of our work around, there are two seperate functions that are called as well that use jquery to hide or show the dropwdown, nothing fancy

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an array controller?

Comment: I've been trying to do but changing it to just an array cause the application to break else where.  I'm still trying to change what I can so that it might work but it's a fairly large project and I'm not the one who wrote it so it's probably taking me longer than it would the creator

Comment: Would you mind replicating the template as well, if you could show it in a jsbin (even if it's working there), we can try and understand it more (emberjs.jsbin.com)

Comment: We discovered that the crashing was occur a bit after the clear() actually. I'm sorry to have waisted your time on something that wasn't actually the issue, I really do appreciate the help so far though.  I have updated my original post to reflect these changes.  I'll make the jsbin to help out hopefully some time tomorrow.  Thanks again for your help so far